# Check status of bit in each index position

Tags: javascript

To give an idea: I want to check if number 2 (0010 in binary), has a a bit turned on in each index position.

```
Lets take binaryInput= 1100
result =[];
```

I have data mapped as below:

```
item1 on ->  0
item1 off -> 1

item2 on ->  0
item2 off -> 1

item3 on ->  0
item3 off -> 1

item4 on ->  0
item4 off -> 1
```

I need to find whichever was "1" and add to the result. So that I can display what was the status for the given input.
In this case, the result has to be [""item3 off", "item4 off"] for binaryInput "1100" (reading from right).

Can anyone guide me how I can go about this. Thank you.

I tried as below:

```
const data = {
    "item1 on" :  "0",
    "item1 off" : "1",
    "item2 on" :  "0",
    "item2 off" : "1",
    "item3 on" :  "0",
    "item3 off" : "1",
    "item4 on" :  "0",
    "item4 off" : "1",  
    }

 function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
 }

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
     var status= getKeyByValue(data, input[i]);
                              
    if (input[i] === "1") {
            result.push(status);
      }                                 
}
```

Comment: using if statements are a good start. Please share your current effort as a [mcve]. If you haven't got any, go try something first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is worth to know that you can `number.toString(2)` in order to have it's binary representation as string. Cool.

Now next thing to note, is that all bits will be 1 if number is 2^n-1 for every integer n. (This is of course not a programming trick).

```js
var x = 63;
console.log(x.toString(2));
var next_log2 = Math.log2(x + 1);
console.log(parseInt(next_log2, 10) == next_log2);

// now for the actual attempt:
var input = "011001"
console.log(input);


var arr = input.split("").reverse();
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === "0") {
    var msg = "item" + (i + 1) + " off"
    result.push(msg)
  }

}
console.log("" + result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, consider input was "1100"(should be read from right as 0011). I am looking for result as ["item3 off", "item4 off]

Comment: That works great, thanks a lot. But as per my requirement, I need to return an array of keys that were "1" ["item3 off", "item4 off] . Because I might as well have some other value other than 'on' or 'off'. I would appreciate if you have suggestions.

Comment: @Sarahrb Just use Array.push() inside the loop instead of printing it to the console then?